# WordPress Page Attributes: Stop users changing the default parent

Tags: page-attributes

I want to restrict the parent menu in page attributes. 
I have set a default parent using the below code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'default_page_parent' );
function default_page_parent( $data )
{
 if ( $data['post_status'] == 'auto-draft' && $data['post_type'] == 'page' )
    $data['post_parent'] = 4418;
return $data;
}
```

Im finding it very hard to find what I need on Google and hoped someone here could advise me.

Is there a way to lock the menu so it can't be changed or remove its from the menu?

Many thanks

Comment: You mean 'disable' the control? Or hide/remove it completely?

Comment: ... or adjust the code snippet to always fix the parent id, except for the parent page? Another approach might be to play with he `page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args` filter to return no pages or just remove it with the `wp_dropdown_pages` filter

Comment: Disabling the control is fine providing that if it is greyed out, the default parent will display in the greyed out control and will be selected (i.e. - the user cannot change the control.

I don't want the user to be able to select any parent other than the default that I have coded in. 

Thanks